# kernel upgrade in ubuntu 12

Tags: ubuntu, kernel

I am using ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS server version. The kernel it has is Linux 3.13.0-32-generic x86_64.

I need to upgrade it to mainline 4.15 version.

I tried many times but i am unable to upgrade.

Upgrading from 3.13 to 4.1 is not a problem,it upgrades without any hassle.

When i try upgrading to anything over 4.1, i found it asks to solve kmod dependencies. I even installed kmod and its all dependencies form this site: 
[Details of package kmod in trusty | Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/kmod). 
With this i still get error of dependency so i had to install module-init-tools to kmod from this site:
[Details of package module-init-tools in wheezy | Debian](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/module-init-tools)

and i did sudo update-grub

After this has been installed,it upgrades to 4.15 after reboot. 
Now i realized it has libc6 version 2.19 and i need to downgrade it else i get this error:

```
root@ubuntu:/usr/src# apt-get install byobu
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 byobu : Depends: python-newt (>= 0.52.2-11) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: tmux (>= 1.5) but it is not going to be installed or
              screen but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: screen but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: tmux (>= 1.5) but it is not going to be installed
 libnih1 : PreDepends: libc6 (< 2.16) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.14 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

And again i have to downgrade this using this command:

```
sudo aptitude reinstall libc6
```

After this i try reboot, i get back to kernel version 3.13 again.

Is it that ubuntu 12.05 can't be upgraded to mainline 4.15 or am i missing something here.

Thank you in advance. Expecting help here.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 is past end of life. Upgrade to a supported Ubuntu release.

Comment: Maybe you were told to shoot your self in the foot (proverbially!), but this site's rules truly say we don't help people to shoot their foots in this way. Time to `do-release-upgrade`.

Answer (score 2):

I tried really hard looking for all the available options in my test machine and could finally upgrade to 4.15 in ubntu 12.04.

This is what i did:

Download [kernel 4.15](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.15/).

Then download the following for solving the dependencies related to installing kernel 4.15:

```
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/k/kmod/module-init-tools_9-3_all.deb
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-4.7/libgcc1_4.7.2-5_amd64.deb
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-4.7/gcc-4.7-base_4.7.2-5_amd64.deb
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/k/kmod/kmod_9-3_amd64.deb
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/k/kmod/libkmod2_9-3_amd64.deb
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/l/lsb/lsb-base_4.1+Debian8+deb7u1_all.deb
```

After downloading, install the files using `dpkg -i *.deb`, and finally `update-grub`.

Reboot the server and check `uname -msr`.

Should work. Your kernel version is upgraded from 3.13 to 4.15